# UNUserNotificationDelegate method is not getting called and notification is not displaying FCM

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, unusernotificationcenter

I am trying to implement FCM in my Application. I have followed the Documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup and created APN'S key and installed the pod files also.

1. Firebase
2. Firebase/Messaging

Now problem is I am getting data in below method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
      FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
}
```

But I am not getting notification and my UNUserNotification Methods are also not getting called.

Below is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Google
import GoogleSignIn
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate , UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    //FireBase
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info_Firebase", ofType: "plist")
    let options = FIROptions(contentsOfFile: filePath)

    //registerForPushNotifications()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_,_ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    //application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    //UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    FIRApp.configure(with : options!)

    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                           name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                           object: nil)
   }

   // [START refresh_token]
   func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {

    if let refreshToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        Helper.sharedInstance.Print(refreshToken as AnyObject)
        Helper.sharedInstance.userDefault.set("\(refreshToken)", forKey: AssessNowKyes.pushToken)
    }

    //Connect to FCM
    connectToFcm()
   }

  //START connect_to_fcm
  func connectToFcm() {
    // Won't connect since there is no token
    guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
        return;
    }

    // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
    FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            Helper.sharedInstance.Print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(String(describing: error))" as AnyObject)
        } else {
            Helper.sharedInstance.Print("Connected to FCM." as AnyObject)
        }
      }
   }
}
```

//MARK :- Notification

```
extension AppDelegate {
//Request for Notifications
func registerForPushNotifications() {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted, error) in

            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
            //Helper.sharedInstance.Print("Permission granted: \(granted)" as AnyObject)

            if granted == false {
                // Helper.sharedInstance.Print("Permission granted: False in Loop" as AnyObject)
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
}

//User Notification
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    // Play sound and show alert to the user
    completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
}

//Recieve response
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // Determine the user action
    switch response.actionIdentifier {

    case UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier:
        print("Dismiss Action")

    case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:

        Helper.sharedInstance.Print(response.notification.request.content.userInfo as AnyObject)

        /*if true == (response.notification.request.content.title).contains("Traffic") {

        }

        else if (response.notification.request.content.userInfo["type"] as? String)?.contains("Reminder") == true {

        }

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [response.notification.request.identifier])
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [response.notification.request.identifier])*/

    default:

        Helper.sharedInstance.Print("Unknown action" as AnyObject)
    }

    completionHandler()
  }
}.
```

//MARK :- FCM DidRegisterRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken

```
extension AppDelegate {
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    //FIRMessaging.messaging().
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .sandbox)
    Helper.sharedInstance.Print(deviceToken as AnyObject)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

    Helper.sharedInstance.Print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)" as AnyObject)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    //Helper.sharedInstance.localNotificationTrigger(title: userInfo["title"]! as! String, body: userInfo["message"]! as! String, identifier: userInfo["gcm.message_id"]! as! String)

    //0:1504338754994223%0dc014bc0dc014bc
    // Print message ID.
    /*if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }*/

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
  }
}
```

Any issue with device or any other thing I am missing? Why I am not getting notification and why UNUserNotification is not working?

Comment: i have the same issue did you solved this?